# send selected dropdown value to another PHP page

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I do not use submit button

I want the selected value from the user sent to the test1.php page, but when the user selects an option nothing happen in the page, and the value is not sent to the test1.php page

Is there any mistake in my code, or did I miss something ?

test2.php

```
<?php include_once 'database.php';

?>


<head>



    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



    <script>


        $(function() {
            $('.category').change(function() {
                var category = $('.category option:selected').val();
                alert('category changed to ' + category);
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "test1.php",
                    data: {
                        category1: $(this).val()
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });



    </script>






</head>
         <p> Filter By Category</p>
    <select id="category" class="category">
                                <?php
                                $query = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from category ");
                                while($category = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                                    echo "<option value='" . $category['cat_name'] . "'>" . $category['cat_name'] . "</option> ";
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>
```

test1.php

```
<?php
include_once 'database.php';

if (isset($_POST['category1'])) {
    $category = $_POST['category1'];
    echo $category;
}
?>
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce with the provided code. What does your `console.log` output?

Comment: nothing in the console.log

Comment: If `console.log` isn't firing at all, it could be a) `test1` and `test2` are not in the same folder or b) as @Artiko suggested, you haven't included jQuery.

Comment: C'mon, try a little harder! :-) Your code works fine - [here's a working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/srn74tm0/).  When troubleshooting, and definitely for posting here on SO, try to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it will help you find and understand the problem, and make it easier for others to help.

Comment: thank you , my all problem now is the data not send to test1.php I will try to solve it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

is that all your file ? did you forget to include jquery ?

I just did the same script as yours but in html, and console said $ not found, after add jquery that's working

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
$(function() {
$('.category').change(function() {
$.ajax({
method: "POST",
url: "https://webhook.site/2d574d22-5570-46f2-b5bd-343d715adff4",
data: {
category1: $(this).val()
},
success: function(data){
console.log(data);
}
});
});
});
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p> Filter By Category</p>
<select id="category" class="category">
    <option value='1'>One</option>
    <option value='2'>two</option>
</select>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is the webhook to check your request, it is like test1.php but just for debugging purpose https://webhook.site/#!/2d574d22-5570-46f2-b5bd-343d715adff4/e3406220-f58e-45be-a4ef-13d8d3e0b0d3/1

here are some advices:

- inspect your page using developer tools, maybe there are some errors
- check with console.log .val()

hope this help

Comment: your test1.php is working fine

```
if (isset($_POST['category1'])) {
    $category = $_POST['category1'];
    echo $category;
}
```

it just echoing your category changes from client

Comment: but way echo $category; not appear in the test1.php , i want the data appear in test1.php page

Comment: @user If you want that data to appear on test1, then AJAX is not what you should be using.

Comment: can you tell me what should I use?

Comment: I what to execute query in another page based on the selected option

Comment: the data will back to client (it is because your echo), but the data is already at the server, you can use $category for query, and return something client.
if you want another page to show $category maybe u should save the value to db from ajax, and make another page to show it then open it from different browser tab

Comment: anyway it seems the discussion already out of topic, it is about architecture right ? pls accept the answer and maybe make another question ?
i dont know why my answer got downvoted :thinking: